# Executable output works fine in PS console, but not in Powershell ISE?

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, powershell-ise, sap-basis

I have an SAP program call sapgenpse.exe.

If i excute the below command from powershell command, the output is perfect.

[image]

But if i  do the same operation in powershell ISE, the output breaks abruptly.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

It **looks like `sapgenpse.exe` outputs to the *stderr* stream** rather than to *stdout*.

Unfortunately, **the Windows PowerShell ISE - unlike the regular console - treats and renders stderr output from external programs as *errors*, even though that isn't appropriate**, given that stderr output cannot be assumed to (always) represent errors.
(I have no explanation for the strange format you're getting, however).

There are two **workarounds**:

- Redirect PowerShell's error stream (through which stderr output is routed in the ISE) to its success output stream, and call the `.ToString()` method on each error record:

```
.\sapgenpse.exe ... 2>&1 | ForEach-Object ToString
```

- Call your executable via `cmd.exe` and use *its* redirection features to redirect stderr to stdout:

```
cmd /c '.\sapgenpse.exe ... 2>&1'
```

---

As an aside:

- **The Windows PowerShell ISE is [no longer actively developed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/introducing-the-windows-powershell-ise#support)** and [there are reasons not to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375) (bottom section), notably not being able to run [PowerShell (Core) 6+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md). The **actively developed, cross-platform editor that offers the best PowerShell development experience** is **[Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)** with its [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell)